# Python logging does not write to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am trying to log some data to a local file like so:

```
import logging

# dont know if format parameter is really necessary here
logging.basicConfig(filename='logs/server_logs.log', filemode='a', format='%(message)s') 

logging.info("some data")
```

This code did generate 0 kb "server_logs.log" file, but it stays empty, no text gets appended to it. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```